# mod rewrite everything but one request_uri

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a project site that has a zend framework in one folder, and a Project Pier (sort of Basecamp) install in a completely different folder (because it was installed way earlier, initially running from another domain).

The domain I registered for this project redirects to the zend/public/ directory with the following rule in my root folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.visiondating.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ files/zend/public/$1 [L]
```

This works fine, but then I figured I wanted the Project Pier page to be accessible from the same domain even though it's running from a completely different location on the server. So I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.visiondating.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cria/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.visiondating.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ files/zend/public/$1 [L]
```

What I'm trying to do here is redirect visiondating.nl/project/index.php to root/cria/project/index.php (where Pier is running), and redirect all other traffic on that domain to Zend.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run Project Pier on `pier.visiondating.nl`. It's easy enough to make `RewriteCond`s filtering that.

Comment: thanks, hadn't thought of that but it does make it a lot easier :)